# Why are all tiles white when using the OpenLayers plugin?

Tags: qgis, qgis-openlayers-plugin, qgis-2.8

I installed the OpenLayers-Plugin and set the CRS to EPSG:3857.

When I go to Web / OpenLayers plugin I get the menu with the various maps, but whatever map I choose, all the tiles are white.
The layer shows up in the legend correctly, if there is another layer underneath, it is hidden by the white tiles.

When I open the OpenLayers toolbar, the small preview map is also white.

What could be the reason?

edit:
The shapefile I used can be found at
www.biooffice.at/java/adscita_geryon_italy.zip

I am adding screenshots with OpenLayers active and off:

[image: active]

[image: off]

Comment: You might be zoomed in too far; try zooming out. You might also have a connection issue (for example if you're behind a firewall). If it's neither of these please post a screen capture.

Comment: I don't think so. I added a point laywer whith points spread out all over Italy. Hannes

Comment: But it could definitely be a firewall issue. What should I ask our admin to do? Open a port?

Comment: Can you provide your shapefile/points and a screen capture of the error? They would really help.

Comment: I've got no problem to load Google street layer with your shapefile, but I've have set CRS options to: " Automatically enable 'on the fly' reprojection...". Have you tried this option?

Comment: thanks, but yes, 'On the fly ..' is enabled!

Answer (score 2):

This looks to me like a network connection problem.

Under `Settings -> Options -> Network`, you can enter proxy settings as needed for your network.

Alternatively, take the project file home and try it on your own computer.

Comment: thanks Andre - yes, it probably is Network/Firewall related. I tried it at home on my linux box, it works. Here at the office, behind a firewall, on Win7, it does not.

Comment: I guess we are on the right track. When I tell him to use the default proxy I get the following error:   `    File "C:/Users/kuehtreiber/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\openlayers_layer.py", line 48, in __init__
    proxy = getProxy()       
  File "C:/Users/kuehtreiber/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\tools_network.py", line 42, in getProxy
    proxy.setPort(settings.value("/proxyPort", 10, type=int))
TypeError: unable to convert a QVariant of type 10 to a QMetaType of type 2 `

Comment: I can't help you on the proxy, because I don't have one ...